# Mi responsive solo funciona al activar la version desktop en el navegador

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive, mediaqueries

Tengo un website, el cual en version portrait en mi movil funciona bien el responsive, pero al pasarlo a version landscape se muestra como se veria en pc grande (aunque la media querie especifica que tome version landscape del sitio)
pero al irme a configuraciones y pedir la version de escritorio me muestra el responsive como deberia de ser, alguien tiene alguna idea de que pueda estar sucediendo ?

Comment: Debes subir el código que estás usando en el sitio para poderte ayudar, **es importante que leas [ask]**, además te invito a que te hagas el [tour] para que sepas cual es el funcionamiento básico del sitio y ganes tu primer medalla !

Comment: @CamiloVasquez puedo subir todo el codigo, podria  subir el link del sitio. http://dev.easygosa.com/tpp/index.php

Comment: Te cuento que en mi móvil se ve perfecto !

Comment: @CamiloVasquez pon en modo landscape osea en modo horizontal

Comment: En definitiva debes mostrar tu código css y la media querie

Comment: @CamiloVasquez pero pasa algo raro, entra en modo horizontal y ve a la parte de contactenos, te daras cuenta que en esa pagina si muestra la version movil es solo en el inicio.

Comment: Y me imagino que utilizas las mismas queries para tooodo el sitio

Comment: @CamiloVasquez si, en todos lados es el mismo codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, intenta con poner esto en tu header.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Saludos